# web2py: Where should I store private, application-specific files?

Tags: python, web2py

I have just started working on web2py. Personally, I find it easier to learn than Django.

My query is that I have to load a file at application startup. Its a pickled hashtable. Where should I store this file so that the system is able to see it

My code is :

```
import cPickle as pickle
def index():
    """
    Load the file into memory and message the number of entries
    """
    f = open('tables.pkl','rb')
    session.tables = pickle.load(f)
    f.close()
    terms = len(session.tables.keys())
    message = 'The total entries in table = ' + str(terms)
    return dict(message=message)
```

As you can see, I have put the code in index() to load it at startup. At present I am using the absolute path upto the physical location of the 'tables.pkl' file. Where should i put it in my application folder.

Also, I want tables variable to be available to all functions in the controller. Is session.tables the right way to go? It is just a search app so there is no user login.
The table has to be loaded only once for all users accessing the page.
Thank you.

Comment: just and add : I have written the code for loading the table and dropped it in models directory. It now loads at startup and is available globally ..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the **private** folder would be a good place for this. You can get the absolute path with:

```
import os
fp = os.path.join(request.folder,'private','tables.pkl')
```

I would use [cache](http://web2py.com/book/default/chapter/04?search=cache#cache) instead of session if the file is not unique per user.

Comment: . Its giving me an error " > from gluon.main import abspath   > ImportError: cannot import name abspath